# Google maps project does not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, responsive-design

I built a map using Google Map's API. It works just as I want it to on desktop, but it does not load on mobile. My site is responsive and I have the width of the map-canvas set to 100%. I read some posts suggesting I need to get rid of my size styling for it to work, but I have not have had luck with this. Can anyone help me with this map? Thanks

This is the webpage where I am running the code. http://stlresidences.com/test-map

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
 #googft-mapCanvas {
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter Address Here">
<div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
<script>
function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
        var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    }

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '1000px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        heatmap: {
            enabled: false
        },
        query: {
            select: "col26",
            from: "11Q0B7iRayT2JIOBl8_VRUmitimhX1W01byuFDnAv",
            where: ""
        },
        options: {
            styleId: 2,
            templateId: 2
        }
    });
    if (isMobile) {
        var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
        var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
        var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
        legend.style.display = 'none';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
        legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
        legendOpenButton.onclick = function () {
            legend.style.display = 'block';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
        legendCloseButton.onclick = function () {
            legend.style.display = 'none';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.64936217820852, -90.53628850000001),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Your New Home",
    });
     // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } 
      else {
         map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(11);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }
      // now let's move the marker
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    });
    //map.fitBounds(bounds);
    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've copied the code from the FusionTable-page, where your styles for `#googft-mapCanvas` will be overwritten.

Remove these 2 lines:

```
mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '1000px';
mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '300px' : '300px';
```

also remove this(there is no `#googft-legend` in your page)

```
if (isMobile) {
    var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
    var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
    var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
    legend.style.display = 'none';
    legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
    legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
    legendOpenButton.onclick = function () {
        legend.style.display = 'block';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
    legendCloseButton.onclick = function () {
        legend.style.display = 'none';
        legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Furthermore: load the release-version of the API

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry,places"></script>
```

Currently you load the experimental API-version which seems to be very unstable

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that the DIV size of your map is somewhat dynamic and that Google Maps can't be painted on load. I suggest you try to run this some time after your page is loaded (like 100ms) to see if it helps. It's usually the best solution for responsive maps, as advised by Google:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

What this code does is basically says to the map to repaint itself as its container size has just changed.